# How to remove the \n from a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, newline

I am trying to create a turtle which goes to the locations on a list and I'm having trouble doing this because my list contains a "\n" after each position. I tried going through the list and changing each one by removing \n from the original to a different one without \n.

I tried `lists.strip("\n")` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
def gotoprocess():

    with open("one.txt", "r") as rp:
        print(rp.readlines())

        lists = rp.readlines()

        while True:
            for i in range(len(lists)):
                lists[i]

                if lists[i] == lists[-2]:
                    break
        print(lists)
```

I expected a list that looks like this

```
['(-300.00,300.00)','(-200.00,200.00)']
```

but with more numbers. 
What I got was this

```
['(-300.00,300.00)\n', '(-200.00,200.00)\n', '(-100.00,300.00)\n', '(-100.00,100.00)\n', '(-300.00,100.00)\n', '(-300.00,300.00)\n', '(-200.00,200.00)\n']
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in the while loop and if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strip("\n")` should work.
But you probably got 2 things wrong:

1. [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is a string method and it should be applied to the string elements (`lists[i].strip("\n")`), not on the list (`lists.strip("\n")`)
2. [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) *returns a copy of the modified string*, it does not modify the original string

What you can do is to create a new list with the stripped strings:

```
lists = ['(-300.00,300.00)\n','(-200.00,200.00)\n', '(-100.00,300.00)\n','(-100.00,100.00)\n', '(-300.00,100.00)\n','(-300.00,300.00)\n', '(-200.00,200.00)\n']
locs = []

for i in range(len(lists)):
    locs.append(lists[i].strip("\n"))

print(locs)
# ['(-300.00,300.00)', '(-200.00,200.00)', '(-100.00,300.00)', '(-100.00,100.00)', '(-300.00,100.00)', '(-300.00,300.00)', '(-200.00,200.00)']
```

You can further simplify the loop with list comprehension:

```
locs = [loc.strip("\n") for loc in lists]

print(locs)
# ['(-300.00,300.00)', '(-200.00,200.00)', '(-100.00,300.00)', '(-100.00,100.00)', '(-300.00,100.00)', '(-300.00,300.00)', '(-200.00,200.00)']
```